# VSCode won't import xgboost in .ipynb

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am using miniconda, created an environment, activated the env, installed several packages using `conda install`, and installed `xgboost` using `pip install xgboost` everything is fine until trying to run `import xgboost` from VSCode, which returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'`. after checking `conda list`, not finding `xgboost` there (I guess that is fine, since i used `pip install`), tried `pip install xgboost` again, which returns `Requirement already satisfied: xgboost in C:\progs\miniconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages (0.90)`

The weird part is that jupyter notebook succesfully imports xgboost, but VSCode doesn't. So this issue seems to be VSCode related.

Tried restarting VSCode, changing active envs, etc, nothing works, until I stumbled upon this `print(sys.base_prefix)`, ran it in VSCode and it returned a different env folder `C:\Progs\Miniconda3\envs\test`.

I am not sure where to go from here. This has proven to be a bit of a tough issue to find solutions to so far. Any ideas on how to make VSCode point to the right env even if it is showing that the correct env is selected at the bottom right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that in VS Code, the python kernel used by Jupyter is a python environment that can be used independently of VS Code, and the python used by the internal terminal is the python interpreter selected in the lower left corner of the new VS Code terminal. Therefore, when changing the selector in the lower left corner, we need to open a new VS Code terminal, which will automatically enter the selected environment.

**Solution**: Please close the current VS Code terminal, click "`Terminal`", "`New Terminal`" (or use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+`) to open a new VS Code terminal.

Please make sure that the conda environment you are using is activated, and the installed modules will be stored in this python environment.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had not noticed the top right corner. Changing it there solved the problem. Thank you :)